# ng-messages asyncValidators

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

I'm trying to write directive to validate if username exists on the server.
If it exists I want to show error via ng-messages.
But for some reason the error doesn't show.I checked server response and it returns right values but looks like validator cannot resolve promise or so...

```js
//Directive

angular.module('main').directive('checkIfUserExists', checkIfUserExists);

checkIfUserExists.$inject = ['authService'];

function checkIfUserExists(authService) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$asyncValidators.checkIfUserExists = function (modelValue) {
                return authService.suchUserAlreadyExists(modelValue);
            };
        }
    };
};

//service method

  suchUserAlreadyExists: function (user) {
            return $http.get(baseUrl + "/api/account/someone/" + user).then(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(response.data);
                return !response.data;
            },function (data, status, headers, config) {
                return $q.reject('error occured');
            });
        }
```

```html
//Input I want to validate

 <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <input type="text" check-if-user-exists ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" ng-maxlength="10" ng-minlength="6"                                   class="form-control" id="username" name="username" ng-model="general.username" placeholder="******"                                 required />
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 inputErrorMessage">
                    <div ng-messages="registerGeneralForm.username.$error" ng-if="registerGeneralForm.username.$dirty">
                        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
                        <div ng-message="pattern">Only alphanumeric characters  allowed</div>
                        <div ng-message="maxlength">Username cannot exceed 10 characters</div>
                        <div ng-message="minlength">Username must be over 6 characters</div>
                        <div ng-message="checkIfUserExists">Such user already exists</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

The return from the $asyncValidators function needs to be a promise. The rejection of the promise "Fails" the validation, the resolve of the promise "Passes" the validation. 
Working Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ravenous52/1e9h2trw/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {}
]);

myApp.directive('checkIfUserExists', [
  '$q',
  '$http',
  function($q, $http) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$asyncValidators.checkIfUserExists = function(modelValue) {
          var defer = $q.defer();
          $http.get(baseUrl + "/api/account/someone/" + user).then(function(isUnique) {
            if (response.data) {
              defer.resolve();
            } else {
              defer.reject();
            }
          }).catch(function(err) {
            // reject with the error message
            defer.reject(err);
          });
          // return the promise
          return defer.promise;
        };
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<section ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ng-form name="registerGeneralForm">
    <input type="text" check-if-user-exists id="username" name="username" ng-model="general.username" placeholder="******" />
    <div ng-messages="registerGeneralForm.username.$error" ng-show="registerGeneralForm.username.$dirty">
      <div ng-message="checkIfUserExists">Such user already exists</div>
    </div>
  </ng-form>
```

Comment: Check this out and see if it helps . Working Fiddle  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ravenous52/1e9h2trw/)

Comment: Your fiiddle works perfectly!The problem was that I thouht that I can set true/false value to resolve method.And it looks like resolve - is true and reject - is false.

Comment: Can you post your comment as answer so I can mark it as right answer?
Thank you a lot!